# css on tables within tables

Tags: c#, .net, css

I generate a Gridview and, in two of the cells of each, there are two other Gridviews. This renders as a table and each row has a table in two of the cells.

I set the CssClass of each Gridview but, no matter what I do, the tables in the calls seem to inherit at least some of the css attributes applied to the containing table.

Is there a foolproof way of saying 'Ignore all the attributes of the table that surrounds this table'.

Comment: You might want to read up on how CSS works.

Answer (score 1):

you could use more specific CSS selectors... e.g.:

```
<table class="outerTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>This will be white text</td>
            <td>

                <table class="innerTable">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>This will be black text</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table

.outerTable > tbody > tr > td {
   color: #fff;
}

.innerTable > tbody > tr > td {
   color: #000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am already doing that. My outer table has a class of Grid2. My inner table has a class of GridNone.

Comment: Sorry, is it just me or is this site incredibly unintuitive to use - the ability to edit is time limited! And, you hit enter in this text box, and the form submits.

Okay, two soft returns later ...

In my style sheet the rules for the inner table were above the rules for the outer table. Moving the rules down the stylesheet to below the rules for the outer table worked! Someone below says the position of the rules makes no difference ... well it does for me.

Answer (score 0):

BLSully is right, the only good way to do this is through overwriting its inherited attributes.  To overwrite an attribute, you need to have overriding code be more specific than other selectors.  For a great article on specificity, read this:

http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html

Comment: the order of the rules are irrelevant it's the specificity that counts

Comment: You know, you don't have to write up your own answer if you're just expanding on someone else's answer.  You could just make a comment containing the additional information.

Comment: If I were the one asking the question, I would appreciate it a clearer explanation instead of just a comment.  Plus, I get to learn as well!

Comment: I think you are just mad that the OP gave me the answer a little while ago instead of you until you went and begged him for it.