# CSS exclude secondary table from nth-child

Tags: html, css

my CSS is as follows. first one works well

```
.tbl_flowers tr:nth-child(even) {
background-color: #c2ddf2;
}
```

however, i have a table which has in the last cell of each row a secondary table class tbl_points

```
.tbl_trees:not(.tbl_points) tr:nth-child(even) {
background-color: #dff0d8;
}
```

what happens is that the rows in tbl_points are getting treated as if they are rows in tbl_trees
Viz: if tbl_trees row is selected, its tbl_points rows are all colored
if tbl_trees row is NOT selected, its tbl_points rows are alternately colored...

I guess I do NOT know how to use the "not" excluder ... two days of frustration so far!

example is [here](http://tdocplus.co.uk/linnpark/index.php/botany/where-to-find-trees).

Thanks
Richard

Comment: Hi Richard, welcome to SO. You need to add some [reprex] so we can test run your code. Failing to do so will get your question downvoted and/or closed.

Comment: To downvoters: at least have the decency to explain to a newcomer what needs to be done to get create a good question.

Comment: I use Joomla, so delivering reproducible code is not so easy ... but I have quoted the link where it happens ....

Comment: I have been writing code in CA_VisualObjects for 20 years, and have raised and answered many many questions - see tdoc.com for my major application. I have explained the problem ... does noone have an answer.

Comment: IBRAHIM EZZAT - Thank you for rephrasing my post. I await some answers ... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple ... I found it here.
[css on tables within tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14839566/css-on-tables-within-tables)

Basically all that was necessary was to improve the selector to this:

```css
.tbl_trees > tbody > tr:nth-child(even) { 
  background-color: #dff0d8;
}
```

So easy when one begins to understand how the selector operates.

Thanks for all help in any event ... and I have now discovered how to post snippets ... the "error message" about inserting code needs to be fixed ! Had me doing the wrong thing.

Richard